# use excel custom functions on another computer

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vba

I have written custom functions in excel 2007 which I'm able to use on my computer. When the workbook is opened on another computer, cell values become #NAME where custom functions have been used. When I press ALT+F11, I see my custom functions.

Is there any way to make the custom functions work without saving them as AddIns? It's a class assignment and when submitted will be used on another computer. I need help!

Comment: Have you tried setting a breakpoint on the first line of your `Function` to see if the code if actually being triggered? If it is, try stepping through the code with `F8` after your code is triggered to see why the calculation is returning `#NAME`.

Answer (score 1):

How have you added the macros/functions to the workbook?

If you've added them to the workbook with your data (and saved it as a macro enabled workbook) then your functions should be available assuming that the security settings on the other computer are set to allow macros too.

If you've added your macros to the default workbook (so there available to you regardless of the workbook you are using) then you will need to either copy the template with your workbook or take the functions you need out of the template and copy them to your workbook.

Comment: I saved it as a macro enabled workbook but did not work, maybe its about the security settings. I will check that. But what is the default workbook you referred to?

Comment: He's referring to the `Personal.xlsb` workbook. It's a hidden workbook that opens every time Excel is opened. This allows a user to create a macro (which is then stored in the `Personal` workbook) that can be used regardless of which file is opened without creating addins.